# Push notification alert comes two times

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I made an application in that I have implemented the push notification but when I send notification through admin panel the notification alert comes two times in my device.  I have created the separate profile and certificate and ck.pem file.

Please help me.

========

```
function sendnote_ios($message,$registatoin_ids_arr_ios){



// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = $message;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
 exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

//echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
 'alert' => $message,
 'sound' => 'default'
 );
 //echo '<pre>';print_r($body);
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
foreach($registatoin_ids_arr_ios as $token){
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', trim($token)) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
 //$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
}

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

/*
if (!$result)
 echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
 echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
*/
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Share some code from server side implementation of push notification.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
<?php
//your device token
$deviceToken = '';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

 // Encode the payload as JSON
 $payload = json_encode($body);

 // Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .      $payload;

 // Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

 if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
 else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```